# Can cross validation be applied to threshold based outlier detection model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, cross-validation, outliers

I have a threshold based outlier detection model.
I apply PCA then calculate the distance from the centre of the features, and use the MSE to differentiate if the datapoint is a outlier. 
However, I was wondering if I can apply cross validation to prevent overfitting.

Right now, my method is: 
1. Spilt data into train, test.
2. Apply PCA on train data and measure the distance from the model, set a threshold. Eg:  >500 is an outlier
3. Den i apply the same pipeline to the test data, and the same threshold.

Qn:
1. Should I use cross validation on the train data set to make it more robust?
2. If I were to use cross validation, when should I use it?

Comment: Do you want to use the cross validation to set the threshold?

Comment: No. I want to use CV to get more train-test set. Because currently im only spilting into train and test